# Reading from JSON using Jackson. Error Cannot deserialize value of type `` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json file:

```
[{"name":"James","height":170.3,"weight":55.945535152517735,"items":[{"name":"Tickle","number":1000},{"name":"Greedy","number":1400}]},{"name":"Mary","height":150.43,"weight":55.943284737579376,"items":[{"name":"Happy","number":1400},{"name":"Nosey","number":1100}]},{"name":"Robert","height":167.21,"weight":55.94449876875712,"items":[{"name":"Sneeze","number":1400},{"name":"Bump","number":900}]},{"name":"John","height":134.32,"weight":55.94390696616939,"items":[{"name":"Snow","number":1400},{"name":"Messy","number":900}]}]
```

And have two classes for the data:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class People {
    private String name;
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private Item item;


//setters and getters
```

}

...

```js
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Item{
        private String name;
        private int number;

        //setters and getters
}
```

I used jackson to read the data:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            People[] usrPost = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://mylink"), People[].class);
            System.out.println(usrPost[2]);
        } catch ( MalformedURLException e ) {
            e . printStackTrace ( ) ;
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e . printStackTrace ( ) ;
        }
    }
    }
```

For some reason I keep on getting the following error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type ` ` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (URL); line: 1, column: 97] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]-> People["item"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1462)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:648)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:24)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3560)
    at uk.ac.ed.inf.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:21)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Think there might be an issue with the second Item class and the fact that I'm reading an array.

Comment: this is not javascript

Comment: try `private List<Item> items;`

Comment: @MarcStroebel instead of ` private Item item; ` ? Didn't seem to work, same error

Comment: did you also modify getter and setter?

Comment: @MarcStroebel yes

Comment: `public Item getItem() {
        return (Item) item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = (List<Item>) item;
    }`

Comment: nope... public List<Item> getItems() ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this modified People class ... in your json, items is an array, so model must fit

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class People {
    private String name;
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private List<Item> items;

    // other getter/setter

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```